# Unable to access sftp server directly from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

I have created a sftp server for linux ec2 instance on aws. I have also mount the s3 bucket on linux using s3fs. 
Now, any third party is able to access the sftp server using WinSCP. However, I am looking for the ways to access this server using browser url.

I have tried something like:
 `sftp://username:password@hostip`

But it opens through the WinScp applocation and not through the browser directly.

Are they any ways to achieve it directly from browser?

Comment: This is [not a programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It would fit on [su]. But it's already answered there: [How do I connect to SFTP server with web browser?](https://superuser.com/q/1475785/213663).

Answer (score 0):

skip the Linux layer and allow direct access to the bucket from the web
as described here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: I don't think this will solve my purpose. I guess using AWS SFTP service will be more relevant option in this case but I'm not sure if it's endpoint can be directly accessed through browser or not. Haven't tried yet.